# Puppet array of positive integers

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and trying to understand how `Array[Integer[1]]` declares an array of positive integers? What does the `1` signify here?

Comment: Looks like the `1` signifies the lower bound of a range that has no upper bound.

Comment: That is correct.  The Puppet docs describe [the significance of `Integer`'s type parameters](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_data_number.html#lang_data_number_integer_type-integer-parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs) page:

> ##### The `Array` data type <sup>[[1]](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_data_array.html#lang_data_array_type)</sup>
>
> > #### Parameters <sup>[[2]](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_data_array.html#lang_data_array_type-parameters)</sup>
> >
> > > `Array[Integer, 6]` means:
> > >
> > > Matches an array containing at least six integers.

Comment: This is responsive to the question only in that it links to the docs.  The specific called-out example, `Array[Integer, 6]`, is not analogous to the OP's `Array[Integer[1]]`.  It doesn't even link to the docs most relevant to the question, which would be those for the `Integer` data type.